# I need help echoing a variable using bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to append the line

> log-bin="/mysql-log/bin-log"

to the file

> /etc/mysql/test

and the following command does the job

> echo 'echo "log-bin=""\"/mysql-log/bin-log\"" >> /etc/mysql/test' | sudo -s

However, I'm having a hard time if I want to have a more flexible script where the line to append is store on a variable. That is by doing something like this:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> BIN_LOG_DIR="\"/mysql-log/bin-log\""
>
> str="log-bin="$BIN_LOG_DIR
>
> echo 'echo ${str} >> /etc/mysql/test' | sudo -s

This script adds an empty line rather that the intended value contained in the variable $str. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!!
gorf

Comment: It would be a lot safer to just `echo "$str" | sudo tee -a /etc/mysql/test >/dev/null` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use single quotes, the variables are nor interpolated, you need double quotes. That's the problem here

So :

```
#!/bin/bash

BIN_LOG_DIR="/mysql-log/bin-log"

str="log-bin$BIN_LOG_DIR"

echo "echo ${str} >> /etc/mysql/test" | sudo -s
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting for explanations about the use of the different quotes.